# Tomcat max RAM in a VPS

Tags: tomcat, resources

I'm going to upload my local Tomcat WebApp to a VPS. I have selected a 2GB RAM VPS, so... how could I know how many GB of RAM should I set in Tomcat for using? I mean, the server has 2GB, but I don't know if it's safe to set 2GB for tomcat or not.

Could anyone give me an advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `-Xmx2g` is a bad idea. You have to take several memory regions into account when deciding on memory settings:

- How much RAM is used by the OS ?
- Metaspace
- Java Heap
- Native memory (used by the thread stacks)

So your `-Xmx` should be a bit less than:

```
Java Heap = ALL_RAM - UsedByOS - MetaSpace - ExpectedNumberOfThreads * StackSize - other ram used by the jvm
```

Comment: Thanks. But there are some elements I don't understand: "metaspace", "stack size",... what's that or where can i found info about them?

Comment: The `metaspace` is the memory region where the JVM stores the loaded application classes. So the bigger your app is, the more metaspace you'll need. The `stack` is a fixed size memory region reserved for each thread by the OS. Usually it's 1MB by default, but can be controlled with the `-Xss` jvm flag